# How to get "yes" and "no" buttons in confirmation box instead of "ok" and "cancel"

Tags: jquery, dialog

I did some research on this above mentioned question.

The code I wrote is:

```
function yesnodialog(button1, button2){
     var btns = {};
     btns[button2] = function(){
         $(this).dialog('close');
     };
      btns[button1] = function(){ 
          alert('Hello...');
      };
      $("<div>Are you sure you want to delete this..?</div>").dialog({
          buttons:btns
      });
}

$('body').on('click', 'button.delete-button', function() {
    yesnodialog('Yes', 'No');
});
```

I'm getting the error as "undefined not a function" near dialog.

Is there any plugin to be added in order to support dialog.

Thanks in advance

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8g7qzwnj/1/

Comment: In js fiddle its working fine. But if I place it in my code its not working.. :(

Answer (score 0):

*I'm getting the error as "undefined not a function" near dialog.*

In case if you are using a function which is in some other file and you are using on other page and that function's js file is not referenced in the page, only then you get this error.

Like:

suppose this file has a function named func1.

```
<script src='file1.js'></script>
```

and you also have a another file named `file2.js` which is using this `func1` function but you forgot to make a reference to this file. Then you'll get the error.

```
<script src='file2.js'></script>
```

so in this case you have to make a reference to both files in stack like this:

```
<script src='file1.js'></script> // func1 is here
<script src='file2.js'></script> // now func1 can be used
```

---

### Solution to your issue:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.js"></script> //<---add this library too.
```

```js
function yesnodialog(button1, button2){
     var btns = {};
     btns[button2] = function(){
         $(this).dialog('close');
     };
      btns[button1] = function(){ 
          alert('Hello...');
      };
      $("<div>Are you sure you want to delete this..?</div>").dialog({
          buttons:btns
      });
}

$('body').on('click', 'button.delete-button', function() {
    yesnodialog('Yes', 'No');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="delete-button">Test</button>
```

Comment: @Niveditha how is your stackorder of js file inclusion look like.

Comment: I included jquery.ui.js in my file..But then I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function yesnodialog(button1, button2) {
var buttonsOptions = {};

buttonsOptions[button1] = function() {  alert(button1);  }
buttonsOptions[button2] = function() { alert(button2); }

// Define the Dialog and its properties
$("<div>Are you sure you want to delete this..?</div>").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "Modal",
    height: 250,
    width: 400,
    buttons: buttonsOpts
});

}
```